# Why does my gcd function in haskell only work when it returns type Writer [String] Int and not Writer String Int?

Tags: haskell, monads

The following code does not work:

```
gcd' :: Int -> Int -> Writer String Int
gcd' a b 
 | b == 0 = do
     tell "gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " \n"
     return a
 | otherwise = do
     tell "gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " \n"
     gcd' b (a `mod` b)
```

When I changed the code to this, it now works:

```
gcd' :: Int -> Int -> Writer [String] Int
gcd' a b 
 | b == 0 = do
     tell ["gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " \n"]
     return a
 | otherwise = do
     tell ["gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " \n"]
     gcd' b (a `mod` b)
```

Although I'd now have to concatenate the list of strings.

I don't understand why my original code doesn't work. Surely, my original code should concatenate the strings from each step to give an overall log. But instead, it gives me the following error message:

```
gcdLogger.hs:6:6: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’
                     with ‘WriterT String Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’
      Expected type: WriterT String Data.Functor.Identity.Identity ()
        Actual type: [()]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        tell "gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " /n"
      In the expression:
        do tell "gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " /n"
           return a
      In an equation for ‘gcd'’:
          gcd' a b
            | b == 0
            = do tell "gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " /n"
                 return a
            | otherwise
            = do tell "gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " /n"
                 gcd' b (a `mod` b)
```

Comment: It parses `(tell "gcd ") ++ sshow a ++ ...`.

Comment: You should use brackets, like `tell ("gcd " ++ show a ++ ...)`.

Comment: Anyone know of a canonical duplicate for the precedence of function application vs any other operator?

Comment: Please, never edit questions to completely change the problem that's asked about. Either edit the new problem to the bottom of the original post (if it's just a small addition), or ask a new question (if it's a substantial new issue). In either case, of course first make sure you've tried to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt does not work since function application takes precedence over operators. So it is parsed as:

```
(tell "gcd ") ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ "\n "
```

In the second attempt, you wrap the strings each time in a singleton list, so then you write a list of `String`s (well all these lists contain one string, but that still does not make these `String`s).

You can solve the problem by adding brackets here:

```
gcd' :: Int -> Int -> Writer String Int
gcd' a b = do
    tell ("gcd " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " \n")
    if b == 0 then
        return a
    else
        gcd' b (a `mod` b)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.CPS> runWriter (gcd' 15 5)
(5,"gcd 15 5 \ngcd 5 0 \n")
```

Note that for debugging purposes, it more convenient for you to use [**`trace :: String -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) instead of a `Writer`, as it will more nicely do what you want.

Comment: I have edited my original question to include the parentheses, but the error message still appears. I wrote this code as an exercise to test my understanding of the Writer monad, hence why I didn't use trace.

Comment: @Purpledragonunicorn: I've tested the proposed solution, and it seems to work. It compiles.

Comment: @Purpledragonunicorn: included sample output when I compile the proposed solution. Perhaps there is a syntax error before/after that code fragment.

Comment: Ah, I realise I forgot to change the type signature in my actual code, and that's why it didn't compile when I added the brackets (my type signature was still Writer [String] Int. Very silly mistake on my part, how embarrassing!